# How to insert data to the additional field which is inside pivot table with laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

My pivot table has additional field...

```
id  |  user_id   | language_id  | level
---------------------------------------
```

and my code:

```
User::find($this->userId)->languages()->attach(['language_id' => $lang_id, 'level' => $level]);
```

but  the result is:

```
id  |  user_id   | language_id  | level
---------------------------------------
1       1            1            null
1       1            2            null
```

actually, second line's language_id must be first line's level...

how can i do it properly like this?

```
    id  |  user_id   | language_id  | level
     ---------------------------------------
     1       1            1            2
```

Comment: Have you checked that `$level` contains what you think it does? What's the code for your `languages` relation?

Comment: http://laravel.io/bin/bE70b

Comment: That's the code for your Language model's `users` relationship, but it's essentially the same issue. Posting an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attach()` works a bit differently. The first parameter is the id or an instance of the other model and the second parameter are other pivot fields:

```
User::find($this->userId)->languages()->attach($lang_id, ['level' => $level]);
```

---

As @ceejayoz mentioned you also don't have `withPivot()` defined in your relationship. That means `level` won't be available in the result. Change that by adding `withPivot()` to both sides of the relation:

```
public function languages() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Language')->withPivot('level');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables), you need to define the pivot table's data columns with the relationship.

```
public function languages() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('User')->withPivot('level');
}
```

Comment: As far as I know that's only for selecting. It doesn't need to be defined to use `attach()`